# Scrapy - can not list deeper links

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I need to create a list of website url. I use Scrapy 2.3.0 for this.
The problem is that the result ('item_scraped_count') is 63 links, but I know there are more.

Is there any way to process deeper levels and pick up the url?

My code below:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy import Item
from scrapy import Field


class UrlItem(Item):
    url = Field()


class RetriveUrl(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'retrive_url'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url'),
    )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = UrlItem()
        item['url'] = response.url

        return item
```

Comment: Have you tried in the settings.py DEPTH_LIMIT = 0 ? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit

Comment: @AaronS Yes, after your comment, I set in `settings.py` variable `DEPTH_LIMIT = 0` but without any results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should allow the crawl to follow to the deeper levels. Try this:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=True),
```

> `follow` is a boolean which specifies if links should be followed from each response extracted with this rule. If `callback` is `None` follow defaults to `True`, otherwise it defaults to `False`.

([From the Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules))